# Calculate an integral

Tags: integration

How is this integral calculated? I can't find anything:

$$\int\frac{x}{x^2+x+1}dx$$

Our teacher taught us a method where we write that: $x^2+x+1=(x+a)^2 + b^2$ and we continue but in that case we don't have the $x$ on the upper, we just have $1$. Is this the method?

Comment: Or you could just use the substitution $u = x^2+x+1$ to end up with $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u}$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**
Note that $\frac{d}{dx} \left[x^2+x+1\right] = 2x+1$ so
$$
\int \frac{xdx}{x^2+x+1}
   = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2xdx}{x^2+x+1}
$$
and the latter integral is
$$
\int \frac{2xdx}{x^2+x+1}
   = \int \frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1} dx - \int \frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}
   = \ln|x^2+x+1| - \int \frac{dx}{x^2+x+1},
$$
and that last integral is in the form you seek.

Answer (score 0):

If you write 
$$x^2+x+1=(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4},$$ then by substituting $t=x+\frac{1}{2}$ we obtain 
$$\int \frac{x}{x^2+x+1}dx=\int \frac{x}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}dx=\int \frac{t-\frac{1}{2}}{t^2+\frac{3}{4}}dt=\int \frac{t}{t^2+\frac{3}{4}}dt-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{t^2+\frac{3}{4}}.$$
The first integral can be calculated by another substitution $t^2=u$, and the second one can be reduced to the basic integral for $\arctan x$.